# array_diff Array to string conversion in error

Tags: php, arrays

I want calculate different two array but i get error;

```
Notice:  Array to string conversion in x.php on line 255
```

And not calculate different.

**Code:**

```
            $db->where('lisansID', $_POST['licence']);
            $mActivation = $db->get('moduleactivation', null, 'modulID');
            $aktifler = Array();
            $gelenler = Array();
            foreach($mActivation as $key=>$val)
            {
                $aktifler[] =   $val;
            }

            foreach ($_POST['module'] as $key => $value) {
                $gelenler[] = $val;
            }
            echo '<pre>Aktifler: ';
            print_r($aktifler);
            echo '</pre>';
            echo '<pre> Gelenler:';
            print_r($gelenler);
            echo '</pre> Fark:';
///line 255: 
            var_dump(array_diff($aktifler, $gelenler));
```

Comment: Which is line 255? The problem is on that line so should be clearer. I can't see that the `foreach` loop in the middle is doing anything either.

Comment: Line 255 var_dump(array_diff($aktifler, $gelenler));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array_diff` can only compare strings or values that can be casted to `(string)`. But the elements of `$aktifler` and `$gelenler` are arrays by themselves, that's why you get this notice (also, converting an array to string always results in the string "Array", so all arrays will be treated as equal).

See [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array-diff):

> **Note:**
>
> Two elements are considered equal if and only if *(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2*. In words: when the string representation is the same.

Use [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/array-udiff) instead, where you can define your own comparison function.

```
$out = array_udiff($aktifler, $gelenler, function($a, $b) {
    // the callback must return 0 for equal values
    return intval($a != $b);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking the final part into steps.

- Take the row,
- Save the output,
- display the output.

thus:

```
$out = array_diff($aktifler, $gelenler);
var_dump($out);
```

You have a typo in your code, on the second foreach the `$value` is not assigned to the array, which is instead given `$val`. That's your problem.

Also you should get into the habit of `unset()`ing values from the foreach loop once the loop has completed.

```
foreach($a as $b => $c){
...
}
unset($b,$c);
```